React Native Build Failed: groovy.json.JsonException in native_modules.gradle During Android Build
PS D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend>> npx react-native run-android --verbose
(node:18992) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
debug Running command "cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081"
Error executing command '[node, D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config, --platform, android]': Command '[node, D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config, --platform, android]' failed with exit code 1.
                                                                                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                

* Where:
Script 'D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 420

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Command '[node, D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config, --platform, android]' failed with exit code 1.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 420

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Command '[node, D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config, --platform, android]' failed with exit code 1.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

    at makeError (D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)       
    at D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)

I was trying to run this app may friend made on my laptop using an external android device this is when i ran into this error
I don't know what this error is or what is going on i tried chat gpt and all but was not able to fix it i don't even understand why this error is there any help would be appreciated!
edit:--
After going through some of the same type errors i came across on SoF
i found that removing some specific line from some files will reveal the real error
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

i removed this line from my build.gradle and settings.gradle file
and got a new type of error
    WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

and this
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
    D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\android\app\src\main\java\com\basense\MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
                             ^
      symbol:   class PackageList
      location: package com.facebook.react
    D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\android\app\src\main\java\com\basense\newarchitecture\MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
                             ^
      symbol:   class PackageList
      location: package com.facebook.react
    D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\android\app\src\main\java\com\basense\MainApplication.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                                            ^
      symbol: class PackageList
    D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\android\app\src\main\java\com\basense\newarchitecture\MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                                          ^
      symbol:   class PackageList
      location: class MainApplicationReactNativeHost
    Note: D:\New folder5\project\project-frontend\android\app\src\debug\java\com\basense\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    4 errors


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
